# Convert JSON to string without including names of the properties in the string

Tags: javascript, json

I want to convert a JSON object to a string, but if I use `JSON.stringify()`, the output string will also contain the names of the properties, which is what I don't want.

I could achieve this by iterating over the object, but I would like a solution that also works for nested objects of any depth.

For example, if I execute the following:

```
let myObject = {
  name: 'Bob',
  preferences: {
    color: 'red',
    food: 'pizza'
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

The output string will be:

```
{"name":"Bob","preferences":{"color":"red","food":"pizza"}}
```

How would I get something like the following?

```
{"Bob","red","pizza"}
```

Comment: Well that would not be valid object..... would it be an array?

Comment: I want the output to be a string, not an object, this is because later I want to check if that string contains other one.

Comment: **Hint:** Recursion loop over values, for each level you have to check for an object or a primitive. Further, I imagine you want an array because that desired output is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to know about the [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method.

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

This can be used to quickly and efficiently get the values of a simple object

```js
let obj = {
  "key1":"val1",
  "key2":"val2",
  "key3":"val3"
}

console.log(Object.values(obj));

//loop to print as string
let objString = "";
Object.values(obj).forEach((val) => {
   objString = objString + " " + val
});
console.log(objString);
```

To actually print as a string or to use a multi-dimensional object you will still need to iterate in some form. Here is an example with a multi-dimensional object.

```js
let testObj = {
  "key1":"val1",
  "key2":"val2",
  "key3":{
    "nestedKey1":"nestedVal1",
    "nestedKey2":"nestedVal2"
   }
}

console.log(Object.values(testObj));

function listAsFlatString(obj){
   var returnVal = "";
   Object.values(obj).forEach((val) => {
     if(typeof val !== "object"){
        returnVal = returnVal + " " + val;
     } else {
        returnVal = returnVal + " " + listAsFlatString(val)
     }
  });
  return returnVal.trim();
}

console.log(listAsFlatString(testObj))
```

Comment: You are right, I didn't know about the `Object.values()` method, I should have done more research. Your answer is very complete, somebody also post an answer about the `Object.values()` method, but I was wondering how to use it for a multi-dimensional object, thank you, I think I will use this approach.

Comment: @AxiomSword No problem that's what this site is for :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

Use recursion and check for object, if not object , push into the result

```js
let myObject = {
  name: 'Bob',
  preferences: {
    color: 'red',
    food: 'pizza',
    children:{
      a: 'hi',
      b: {
        c: 'd'
      }
    }
  }
};


let res = [];

function goInto(obj){
   for(let key in obj){
      if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        goInto(obj[key]);
         return;
      } else {
        res.push(obj[key])
      }
   }
}

goInto(myObject);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is simple and achieve what I wanted, however, I'm not sure which approach is more efficient, if yours or the one in @ChrisM answer, for now I will be using @ChrisM 's due to the use of the `Object.value()` method.